# How to design the navigation in a php tool/website?

Tags: php, html

I'm designing a semi-basic tool in PHP, I have more experience server side, and not in PHP.

My tool contains 10-15 pages, and I am doing the navigation between them with the `$_GET` parameter.

In my code I have many if statements that look like:

```
if(isset[param1] && !isset[param2] && .....&& !isset[paramN]){
    // code
}
```

You will agree with me, it's ugly, right?

Is it *"how we do it"* in PHP? or is there some kind of design pattern / functions for navigation in a PHP website?

Edit: To be clearer, what I want to know is: Is the proper way to design the navigation is with plenty of `$_GET` variables?

Comment: I follow a pattern like this `/{page-name}-{id}/` and handle the URL via `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solution to this problem is a little bit complicated, than it might seem at first glance. And you need to implement a handler for that, since you're looking a cleanest way of handling GET parameters and invoking a code fragment.

In your case, your final API, should look like this (since you were asking for the design, not the for implementation):

```
$nav = new Nav($_GET);
$nav->whenSet('param1', 'param2')->andNotSet('param3')->then(function(){

});

$nav->whenSet('param3')->andNotSet('param1', 'param2')->then(function(){

});

// Or a simpler and shorter way
$nav->register($existingKeys, $nonExistingKeys, function(){

});
```

Another option you have is to use a routing mechanism. Most PHP frameworks provide this functionality. They all support optional route fragments, so you can handle parameters only defining one route path, like this `/page/?` (? - means optional).

Comment: Thank you. I guess there is actually no trick / really simple way. And this is the answer, which is really interesting.

Comment: @Upsilon42 Let's define terms clearly. What you need is a handler. PHP hasn't built-in handler for that. PHP has functions which can be used for building handlers. A handler is just a next level of abstraction, which should be provided by your library or a framework.

Comment: Yes yes, it's clear to me :) i will not implement/use some routes framework for 10 pages. But I wanted to know if there was some kind of built-in framework/ design pattern. So for now I will use Objective_d's answer, which is cleaner than what I have, and wont take too much work for 10 pages.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a huge if else statement try a **switch** statement:

```
$param1 = 'something';

switch (true){

    case isset($param1):
    echo "PARAM 1 is set";
    break;

    case isset($param2):
    echo "PARAM 2 is set";
    break;

    default:
    echo "None set";

}
```

And to answer your edit - Yes, you can use `_GET` variables for navigation and it is normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion add conditions in an array and than use `in_array()`

```
echo in_array($yourVar, array('abc', 'def', 'hij', 'klm', 'nop'))
      ? True 
      : false;
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$get = "abc";
$navigation = array(
"abc"=>"yourneed",
"def"=>"yourneed2",
"ghi"=>"yourneed3",
);

foreach($navigation as $key => $value){
if($key == $get){
echo $value;
}
}
```

One more solution you can define routes also.
Same as CI and YII.

Comment: Thanks, interesting but this is not really what Im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not using switch but you should definitely try that, and try using break between cases)

I'm using this at the moment, it seems to avoid mass-IFfing:

```
if (!$_GET) {
    homePageFunction();
}elseif($_GET) {
    contentPagesFunction($_GET['p']);
}
```

I have a menuer() function that outputs rel paths to content 'things' in links like:

```
<a href='?p=$relPath'>$name</a>
```

Although I could probably use different notation to tidy it further... Untested but like this:

```
if     (!$_GET) homePageFunction();
elseif  ($_GET) contentPagesFunction($_GET['p']);
```